# SetArrayArgument, is it really the last or lenth?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I need to set side effect to an array size of 2, looking at the following defienition:

[image]
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md

It seems like for array size of 2 the arguments should be (d.a, d.a + 1), but it does not work, only one of the array elements gets the right value.  The following code works every time:

```
EXPECT_CALL(BFO, get(_, 2))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArrayArgument<0>(d.a, d.a + 2), Return(2)));
```

I am a bit confused, why do I need to add two for array size of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is a bit weird, but [first, last) is [first, last[ or [first, last-1]. The last value is not included.

> An integer interval that has a finite lower or upper endpoint always
>   includes that endpoint. Therefore, the exclusion of endpoints can be
>   explicitly denoted by writing a .. b − 1 , a + 1 .. b , or a + 1 ..
>   b − 1. Alternate-bracket notations like [a .. b) or [a .. b[ are
>   rarely used for integer intervals.

From [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: I was wondering if the bracket and peren combination was a typo, but I understand now...